# Given 2 bootstrap datetimepickers, how do I limit the range of one based on the other?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to restrict the date picker of bootstrap. If I select a date from StartDate picker then I want the EndDate picker to only show dates and times up to 365 days ahead of the StartDate.  How can I achieve this?  Thanks in advance.

So far, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    //language:  'fr',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    showMeridian: 1,
    todayBtn: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
    initialDate: new Date(),
  });

  $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
    language: 'fr',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 1,
    minView: 0,
    maxView: 1,
    forceParse: 0,
    endDate: '+365d'
  });
});
```

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demo what you have already

Comment: check the docs, you can pass dates to disable https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disableddates